# Measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A function is called measurable if the pre-image of measurable set is measurable set.

If you have a measurable function, is the pre-image of non-measurable set non-measurable ?

Comment: No, take the function $f(x)= 1$. The preimage is always measurable.

Comment: @copper.hat could you please explain a little bit ? What is the non measurable set ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course not.

A trivial example is that the $\sigma$-algebra of the range is the trivial one, that is, the whole space and empty one. Then any proper non-empty set is a non-measurable set in the range.

$\textbf{Edit:}$
An explicit example of the idea above:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ $x\mapsto x$ and equip the domain with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra while equip the range with the trivial $\sigma$-algebra. Then $f$ is measurable and a non-measurable set $[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$ have the preimage $[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$ where the latter is measurable.

Comment: Does your answer mean that pre image of non measurable set is measurable ?

Comment: I meant that the preimage of a non-measurable set may be measurable.